# how to integrate twitter in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am integrating twitter in my iphone application.when i am entering the username and password and clicking the login button it navigates me to the updateController page where user can post tweet but when i click on the post tweet button it gives me an error that

A server with the specified hostname could not be found. http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml   and the comment that i have entered does not get posted to my  twitter account.

Please help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider using Twitter OAuth rather than username/password authentication since Twitter will be dropping support for basic auth on August 16.

Here are some Obj-C OAuth libraries that Twitter recommends to get you started:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#objectivec

Answer (score 0):

I think you done all think properly but you must the comment the this line [newCredential release];